# MS Access 2007 Add a new control field to report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have made a report using the report wizard in MS Access. After generating the report I realized that I want to add another value from table (the table is already being used within the report) that I did not include in the report wizard when I generated the report. I have tried adding the new value using the control source option, but it has failed to show up. Please assist in any way you can! Thank you so much for your time. The value I want to add is in table 'tblAuthor' value 'Genre'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the report in design view and check the Record source for the table. If it is a query, you can use the three dots (...) to edit it and ensure it includes Genre. If it is a table, presumably Genre is included. You can then use Add Existing Fields to add a control to the report.